# RStudio v1.1.456 Rpubs upload error, no login prompt

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi I couldn't find any useful information in regards to this one.
When I try to publish to Rpubs on Rstudio v1.1.456, instead of login prompt I get this error message below.
[Edited] Rstudio v1.1.456, R v3.5.1

> Upload Error Occurred Error in if (result$status == 201) succeeded <-
>   TRUE :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed Calls:  In
>   addition: Warning message: In http(protocol, "api.rpubs.com", port,
>   method, path, headers,  :   NAs introduced by coercion Execution
>   halted

I've already addded this line

```
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")
```

to both global and working directory Rprofile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there was an issue in the most recent version of rsconnect (0.8.12).

> devtools::install_github("rstudio/rsconnect", ref = "bugfix/multi-status-header")

Installing the patch solves it.