# 302 Found while uploading to RPubs

Tags: r-markdown, web-publishing

I'm trying to upload a knitted HTML RMarkdown file to RPubs. I knitted the .rmd and click publish in the preview window then selected RPubs then it gives me this window:
[image]

What can i do to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I was getting this error as well. I fixed it by updating rsconnect, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716425

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages('rsconnect')
library(rsconnect)
```

I had the same problem, reinstalling **rsconnect** package solved it for me :)